# Oracle SQL - Missing Expression

Tags: sql, oracle

What is wrong with my code?

```
SELECT PATIENT_NO, DRUG_NO
FROM PRESCRIPTION
WHERE DRUG_NO = 2100 AND BETWEEN, TO_DATE('25/JUN/2016', 'DD/MON/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('05/AUG/2016', 'DD/MON/YYYY');
```

I need the drug number 2100 given between the date 25 june 2016 to 5 august 2016

Thanks

Comment: remove the comma here. `AND BETWEEN, TO_DATE(`

Comment: Missing column name as well...

Comment: What is your exact Problem? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Add teh column Name which should be between the Dates `AND <column name> BETWEEN`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PATIENT_NO, DRUG_NO
  FROM PRESCRIPTION
 WHERE DRUG_NO = 2100 
   AND YOURDATECOLUMN BETWEEN 
           TO_DATE('25/JUN/2016', 'DD/MON/YYYY') 
       AND TO_DATE('05/AUG/2016', 'DD/MON/YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a date value for the two dates to be between:

```
SELECT PATIENT_NO,
       DRUG_NO
FROM   PRESCRIPTION
WHERE  DRUG_NO = 2100
AND    date_column
         BETWEEN TO_DATE( '25/JUN/2016', 'DD/MON/YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH' )
             AND TO_DATE( '05/AUG/2016', 'DD/MON/YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH' );
```

If you are expecting dates in a particular language then you may need to specify that language in the query. Otherwise you could use an ANSI date literal (which is independent of the date language):

```
SELECT PATIENT_NO,
       DRUG_NO
FROM   PRESCRIPTION
WHERE  DRUG_NO = 2100
AND    date_column BETWEEN DATE '2016-06-25' AND DATE '2016-08-05';
```